# Using R for parallel processing while maintaining final order

Tags: r, parallel-processing, time-series

I need to make one my cross validation routines faster. Parallelizing it seems to be the quickest way to see some improvement in speed since I don't own the code it calls.

However, I am dealing with time series data - so the output should stay in the order it would be if it was done sequentially.

Is there any way to run a series of processes on the time series (call them A, B, and C) and wait for all of their results before merging them together in the order of A -> B -> C? I figure for this task a mutex wouldn't be appropriate. I'd need to wait for all subtasks to finish and then merge them manually in the correct order.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parallel loop functions in R preserve order.  Foreach, mclapply, etc.